# Doesn't show Bangla in aspx page but html page shows

Tags: html, asp.net, character-encoding

I have a Invoice type page which have some Bengali words.

> If the page format is *.aspx it shows result like this [image]

but with the same code.

> If the page format is *.aspx it shows result like this, That I want. It's Bengali. [image]